# Azure: linking existing benefits

Tags: azure, bizspark

We have a BizSpark Azure Account and want to contact the Azure support. We have to link existing benefits before it is allowed to contact the support (please have a look at the screenshot http://picpaste.de/Azure_BizSpark_Access_ID_and_Contract_ID___Password.PNG).

Where do we find the "Access ID" and what is the contract ID/Password?

Answer (score 0):

I live in Southeast Asia, you need to email MS to get the Access ID and password:
For SEA bizspark users, email them at `==gtscpro---at---microsoft---dot---com==`

=================

According to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/bb266240

If you haven’t set up your Contract ID and Access ID, you’ll need to do so before you can take advantage of your technical support benefit. This is a one-time setup process and enables you to submit technical support incidents online or via phone anytime you need assistance.

Subscribers in Europe, the Middle East, and Africa: Follow the activation instructions included on http://support.microsoft.com/activatesupport.

Subscribers in all other geographies:
Call your country’s Microsoft Technical Support number and inform the agent that you need to set up a support contract for your Visual Studio subscription. They’ll provide you with a Contract ID and Access ID.